# Using casablanca on windows server

Tags: c++, rest, casablanca

Does the casablanca c++ Rest API support windows server as a platform?

http://casablanca.codeplex.com/documentation

I do not see it on the documentation.

Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see why you would ask, since the chart does not specify windows server explicitly.  But the answer is **absolutely**.

In this case, they should have labeled the first column 'Windows Desktop / Windows Server'.  Windows desktop and windows server utilize the same API in this case, which is very likely why windows server was omitted in the table.

Specifically, they both utilize [WinINet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385331(v=vs.85).aspx) and [WinHTTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384273(v=vs.85).aspx).  Other windows variants (i.e. store / phone / etc) utilize other APIs to accomplish the same tasks.